# Swagger is giving error when I try to pass json object in Get API as query string parameter in C# ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

Swagger is giving error when I try to pass json object in Get API as query string parameter in C# ASP.Net. I read the solution of the similar issue post where it was suggested to update the OpenAPI to 3.0. I tried adding [FromQuery], SwaggerUI throws error saying Ambiguous call.

```
    // GET: api/user/list
    [HttpGet("list")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Filter options = null)
    {
```

#Code
}

Error=>
TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.

Comment: Sure, `Get` methods don't have body, what did you expect here? As for ambiguous call, apparently you already have other conflicting `Get` methods in your controller - remove them or change their routes to eliminate the conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': **Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.**

As the error message states a GET or HEAD action cannot have a body. If you want to pass on some state then your options are either to:

1. Move these variables to the query string (e.g. `/api/user/list?filter=ABC`).
2. Use a different HTTP verb like POST, which *does* allow body parameters.

Note that technically you *can* create a GET-request with a body, it's just highly discouraged and most frameworks like the ones you're using will stop you from doing this.